# Why does this error occur when choosing Orientation in LinearLayoutManager RecyclerView with KOTLIN

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment, orientation, stickyrecycleview

```
On Fragment file:

override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

        recycle_home.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager( this.context , LinearLayout.VERTICAL ,false )
        recycle_home.adapter = adapter_home()

    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0wmR.png)

Comment: You can check correct answer

Answer (score 0):

```
 override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) { super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

        recycle_home.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager( this.context)
        recycle_home.adapter = adapter_home()

    }
```

Or

```
       override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) { super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

            recycle_home.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager( this.context,RecyclerView.VERTICAL,false)
            recycle_home.adapter = adapter_home()

        }
```

Comment: Your welcome, you can check correct answer @ZekriMebrouk

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to add layout manager to RecyclerView you can add it inside xml itself

```
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/emailsRV"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:adapter="@{adapter}"
        android:layoutAnimation="@anim/layout_animation_from_bottom"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/addNewACB"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:listitem="@layout/item_phone" />
```

Then if you want to add orientation you can add it in fragment or you can even create a BindingAdapter for the same

Below is the code for fragment/activity

```
recycle_home.addItemDecoration(DividerItemDecoration(context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL))
```